# From a Windows batch file, how can I determine the exe path for given app running on a RDS with multiple users/instances of the app?

Tags: batch-file, remote-desktop, rds, wmic

From a batch file, how can I determine the executable folder for all instances of a given application that are running on a remote desktop server (RDS) with multiple users and instances of the same app?

While on the RDS, I have tried this command:

```
wmic process where "name='myapp.exe'" get ProcessID, ExecutablePath
```

That command gives me the PID of all instances of myapp.exe that are running on the RDS, BUT it only gives me the ExecutablePath for *MY* instance of the app.  I need the ExecutablePath for ALL instances of the app.

If I go to the task manager GUI, I can see the associated paths there, but I need to be able to associate a PID and an ExecuteablePath from a batch file.

And I do have admin permissions on the RDS.

How can I get that?

(My end goal is to be able to find which instance of the app is in a given directory and kill that instance.)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer.  Even though I am an admin of the RDS, I have to start cmd.exe using "Run as Administrator" and execute the command that way, then I get the ExecutablePath for ALL the processes!